# ViewWill/DidAppear not being called when presenting by navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

For some reason, my viewWill/DidAppear methods aren't being called. Here is the way I'm presenting my view controller:

```swift
let profileViewVM = ProfileViewViewModel()
let profileViewController = ProfileViewController(viewModel: profileViewVM)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(profileViewController, animated: true)
```

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  // <---- breakpoint set here gets hit

    // do stuff
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)  // <---- breakpoint set here does NOT get hit

    // do stuff
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)  // <---- breakpoint set here does NOT get hit

    // do stuff
}
```

Every other question I've seen with this issue has been something to do with not setting up a child controller correctly, not calling the super methods, or calling the wrong super message. This isn't a child controller - it's being presented by a navigationController, and as you can see I'm calling the correct super methods. I'd appreciate any input on why these aren't being hit, I'm stumped

Comment: after set breakpoint in viewDidLoad, have you tried to view your view hierarchy using Debug View Hierarchy? My guess is your profileViewController might be deinit. Only theoritical assumption and you should make some breakpoint to find it out.

Comment: It isn't deinitialized, it's the top viewController

Comment: Then I would argue if your viewController's frame is CGRectZero?